Pandas - Countifs
I'm trying to figure out a way to use a countifs formula from excel in pandas
Looking for the help of you experts!
So I have 1 DF which is an excel file
DF = has a list of names(c34) & about 12 columns
I'm trying to count the empty cell onto another worksheet with the names being the reference point
sample data:

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Jas", "Carl", "Bob", "Jon", "Alice"],
    "Age": [23, 24, 22, None, None, 27, 23],
    "Weight": [71, 67, 51, 75, None, 67, 71],
    "Height": [49, 59, 54, None, 59, 56, 49]
})

example. If Alice exists in DF, then count the empty cells on whatever column 'Age' is on and paste the number in another cell for Alice on another sheet , and subsequently do the same for bob, carl etc going down
Ps, Do I need to do this using a dictionary or can I straight pull from the file?
thank you!

So just looking at this again
I need to count empty cells for each name under each category, so  Age, height , weight etc then just paste it into another sheet

Cound you post a minimum reproducible example, and your expected output (both as text rather than images)? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

what is your exact desired output? provide desired output as table.

The following code will iterate over every unique name in your dataframe and count the number of blanks in the Age column. Then construct a new dataframe with the count of blanks for each name. There is no way to do this directly into an Excel sheet, but you can save the blank_df dataframe as a csv and import that into Excel
blank_names = {}

for name in df["Name"].unique():
    count_of_blank = (df["Name"] == name) and (df["age"].isnull() or (df["age"] == '')).sum()
    blank_names[name] = count_of_blank

blank_df = pd.DataFrame([k + (v,) for k, v in blank_names.items()], columns=["Name", "blank_count"])
print(blank_df)


Apologies to all if i didn't give enough info
@wyatt - thanks for this!  this is what i was looking for as a foundation
I've used this to pop it into an excel file:
with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file) as writer:
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='MissingFields', index=False)
